# How to Label Multiple Geocode Locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a page in my application that's trying to display a number of addresses on the map. I'd like to be able to label them in numerical order and display the relevant data about the location in an InfoWindow. Here's my code

```
//init info window
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
var onMarkerMouseover = function() {
    var marker = this;
    infoWindow.setContent(marker.details);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
}

var form = document.getElementById('routeOptions');
    var i;
    var post_data = '';
    var wo_count = 1;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var addressMap = {};

    for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        if (form.elements[i].id.indexOf('maploc') == '0') {
            if (form.elements[i].id.indexOf('[start]') > 0
                || form.elements[i].id.indexOf('[end]') > 0) {
                continue;
            }

            var values = form.elements[i].value.split('::');
            var address = values[0] + ', ' + values[1] + ', ' + values[2] + ', wo_count:' + wo_count
            var latLng;

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {
                    var content = 'WO#:&nbsp;' + jq('#wo_number_'
                        + wo_count).html() + '<br />'
                        + $('#address_'+ wo_count).html()+'&nbsp;'
                        + $('#city_'+ wo_count).html()+',&nbsp;'
                        + $('#state_'+ wo_count).html()+'&nbsp;'
                        + $('#zip_'+ wo_count).html()+'<br />'
                        + $('#work_type_'+wo_count).html();

                    //draw the marker
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0]['geometry']['location'],
                        map: window.map,
                        label: wo_count+"",
                        details: content
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', onMarkerMouseover);

                    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find address. Contact Support if the problem persists");
                    return;
                }
            });

            wo_count++;
        }
    }
```

The main issue with this code is that although wo_count as a variable is available to the callback function as defined the value of it will be wrong every time. For example, if I have 3 addresses then the value of wo_count will always be 4 for each location because the code to increment it finishes faster than google can respond. I can't just assign the number in the order the responses come back either because google might not return my responses in order. Is there a way I can get my wo_count variable to be correct on each iteration to assign the correct index to the icon and retrieve the correct address data for the Info Window on each location?

Comment: I would refactor so you can create closures around a memoized count variable that only a single geocode callback can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a closure around your counter would allow you to keep a persistent reference to it. Something like this might work:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('routeOptions');
var i;
var post_data = '';
var wo_count = 1;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var addressMap = {};

for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (form.elements[i].id.indexOf('maploc') == '0') {
        if (form.elements[i].id.indexOf('[start]') > 0
            || form.elements[i].id.indexOf('[end]') > 0) {
            continue;
        }

        geocodeWrapper(form.elements[i].value.split('::'), wo_count)

        wo_count++;
    }
}

function geocodeWrapper(values, wo_count) {
    var address = values[0] + ', ' + values[1] + ', ' + values[2] + ', wo_count:' + wo_count
    var latLng;

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            var content = 'WO#:&nbsp;' + jq('#wo_number_'
                + wo_count).html() + '<br />'
                + $('#address_'+ wo_count).html()+'&nbsp;'
                + $('#city_'+ wo_count).html()+',&nbsp;'
                + $('#state_'+ wo_count).html()+'&nbsp;'
                + $('#zip_'+ wo_count).html()+'<br />'
                + $('#work_type_'+wo_count).html();

            //draw the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0]['geometry']['location'],
                map: window.map,
                label: wo_count+"",
                details: content
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', onMarkerMouseover);

            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        } else {
            alert("Unable to find address. Contact Support if the problem persists");
            return;
        }
    });
}
```